# Cambiar valor de un estado en React

Tags: reactjs

Estoy intentando pasar los errores de los campos de registro de mi formulario en un estado, Primero meto los valores del formulario en el useState user y después cuando comienzo a comprobar si alguno de los campos está vació meterlo en un useState errors indicando el campo y el error que tiene.
E intentado inicializar vacio errros no, inicializarlo, inicializarlo con los campos y no consigo que se actualice.
También e comprobado los valores que añado la constante y nada sigue sin funcionar.
Estas son mis constantes:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Y este el resto del código,
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
El console.log(key+"Esta vació") me devuelve todos los campos que se encuentren vacíos, ej: UsernameEsta vacio

Comment: ¡Bienvenido Ramon! Debes de editar tu pregunta y compartir tu código cómo texto usando las herramientas provistas, utilizar imágenes para compartir código son muy mal vistas por la comunidad. Para evitar esto te recomiendo que te des una vuelta por el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) (Aquí podrás obtener tu primer medalla) y de paso ojea [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Para debuggear aconsejo hacer un `console.log` como primera linea de la funciona `upgradeUser`.

Como comentaron lo ideal es que muestres el codigo completo (en formato texto como lo hago aquí abajo). Por ejemplo sería ideal que mostraras tu `return` de este componente. O inclusive el texto completo de este componente.

Cabe mencionar que es preferible evitar el uso de `useState` para objetos. Puedes imaginar un caso más complejo que el tuyo en donde un objecto tiene otros objetos dentro de él con varios niveles de profundidad. `useState` te obligaría a manejar y duplicar el objeto constantemente lo cual no es deseable. Aunque parezca (y a vece lo es) más código, tener un useState para cada una de las llaves tiende a ser más eficiente al final (en cuestión de uso de memoria y cpu).

Dicho lo anterior, lo que necesitas es implementar la **función** de `setUser` y `setError`. Detrás del `hook` hay funciones que modifican y regresan valores, no valores en sí mismo. Por lo que cuando quieres modificar tu objecto necesitas implementar la función de `setUser`:

```
const upgradeUser = (event) => {
    setUser((prevState) => ({
       ...prevState,
       [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    }));
}
```

Lo mismo con `upgradeError`.

Algunos "protips" para mejorar el código estéticamente:

- Considera usar buenos nombres de variables. Por ejemplo usa lowercase para las llaves de tu objeto.
- Considera usar patrones claros para nombrar tus funciones. En tu caso tal ves renombrar `upgradeUSer` a `userOnChangeHandler`, o igual `onChangeHandler` si es un componente básico. Esto hace que en tu HTML puedas hacer algo como:

```
const onChangeHandler = (event) => {
  setUser((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState,
    [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    }));
...
<Input 
    name='firstname'
    value={user.firstname} 
    onChange={onChangeHandler} 
/>
...
```

- Intenta mantener tus bucles/loops sencillos. En cierto punto es una cuestión de preferencia pero yo re-escribiría tu `validate` como:

```
const validate = () => {
  for key in Object.keys(user) {
    if (!user[key]) {
      console.log(`El campo ${key} está vacío.`);
      upgradeError(key, "This field is required");
    }
  }
}
```

- Estos y otros problemas pueden ser fácilmente identificados con una combinación de linters y formatter. Aconsejo buscar informacion sobre `eslint` y `prettier`

Comment: Gracias lo e solucionado, me a sido muy útil tu comentario, tendré en cuenta lo de la foto. Para solucionarlo e cambiado error de estado a objeto y ya no hay problema.

Comment: si mi comentario te ayudó no olvides votar o seleccionarlo como solución. O si lo prefieres, puedes tambien reponder tu propia pregunta y seleccionar tu respuesta como la solución. Así ayudas a muchas más personas en el futuro.